# Can you not add a DB user to an Azure SQL instance from the portal?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

It's the year 2017, I'm wondering if you can you add a DB user to an Azure SQL instance from the portal? Or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've needed to do this recently.  I added the user from the portal, but it was still by issuing commands in the SQL window within the portal as opposed to clicking a button labeled "Add Login".  As far as I know, you still either need to use SSMS or straight SQL